# Exporting child-of constraint with multiple actions

Tags: animation, armature, constraints, unity

I'm animating multiple armatures, FPS arms and a weapon that is attached to the arms hands using a child of constraint.

The issue is that I have multiple actions, and when exporting the child of constraint on the gun will use the animation data from whatever arm animation i selected last.

I.e if i export the gun animations and i selected the "equip" animation last for the arms, the gun will have the equip movement from the child of constraint for each animation.

Is there any way to tell blender that the gun "equip animation" should be paired with the arm "equip animation" so that when exported, the child of constraint uses the right animation to get it's offsets from? or am i going about this all wrong?[image]

Comment: You don' t export constraints, you export keyframes. Normally you would bake the constraint's motion into keyframes when creating each animation "action" in Blender

Comment: one thing i'm not trying to do is to bake the animation, that means every single time i want to make a slight change to the hand movement, id have to add the child of constraint again and rebake it :(

Comment: Not if you bake at export only and don't save your work file after baking

Comment: even doing that, going through each animation and baking every time i make a small change would be painful, is there any sort of script that maybe automates baking all the actions or something like that?

Comment: AFAIK most of Blender's exporters have an animation baking option. I don't know if it works on a per-action basis, but it's worth the try.

Comment: yeah all the exporters have animation baking but it's still the same problem as they'll bake with the last selected arm animation, ive looked around for hours now and it seems like most people just deal with manually baking stuff so i guess im just gonna have to do that, thanks anyways though :)

Answer (score 0):

okay so looks like the only way to do it is just to bake the animations using "visual transform" then disabling the child of constraint for each animation

it makes life slightly easier if you just keep the child of constraint on the animation but keeping it at 0, if in the future you want to rebake it you can just put it back to 1 and rebake